# Packaging for node.js services - .war-like

Tags: node.js, package, release, distributed

If I want to package a `node.js REST` service and distribute it to different `node.js` servers making it pluggable to any server, what's a good way to do it?

Namely, is there something similar to the concept of a `.war` in Java Web environments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not anything similar to `.war`, per say -- but the recommended way is to create a Node module by declaring a `package.json` for your project. This article (http://browsenpm.org/package.json) does a pretty good job of explaining what it does, how it works, and why it is useful.

Answer (score 1):

You might also consider using [Docker](http://www.docker.com) which allows you to distribute your application with all of its requirements, in a virtualized container.

It works natively on Linux and using VirtualBox on Windows and OSX.

Docker is a really interesting tool because it allows you to run your application in its own virtual Linux (or BusyBox or...) where its only access to your host operating system is what you permit. So not only does it provide virtualization, but isolation as well.

To run your app under Docker, you'd select a Node-specific Dockerfile (one that defines all of the prerequisites for running Node including which operating system you want), add your own install commands to it (it's a text file with very minimal syntax), build the "image" and run it. By sharing Dockerfiles, you can share your app with others, and all they need are the Docker specific tools.